# Config file missing when running Confluent Platform

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

When I start confluent platform I get an error `[ERROR] unable to load config: unable to parse config file: /home/user/.confluent/config.json: unexpected end of JSON input`. There is no file in the path shown in the error.

Answer (score 0):

Unexpected EOF would suggest the file is present. `.confluent` directory is hidden, so it's not clear how you've checked if the file exists.

Try `ls -laR`~/.confluent`or`find $HOME -name config.json`...

In any case, `kafka-server-start` should work fine, and I suggest using it

Comment: I should have mentioned that initially the error was `path/config.json file missing` and I could not start zookeeper and kafka. So I created a file in the path shown. After that Zookeeper and Kafka is running but I get the error `unable to load config` in the beginning. I was wondering if I was missing any config data that needs to be in that file.

Comment: I don't actually know what data goes in that file. I assume you're using `confluent` command to start things? That's not to be used in production environments, and Docker compose works just as well locally